# How to send onError if result is invalid in RxJava

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I have implemented a POJO like so.

```
public class WebResponse<T> {

    private String Response;
    private String Message;
    private T Result;
}
```

As an example if `Response` is success, I will receive an Array of countries in `Result`.

To perform composition operations on the `Country`s only I `flatMap`'d the WebResponse and applied the relevant operators. Like so:

```
    Observable<WebResponse<ArrayList<Country>>> countryListAsObservable = api.getCountryListAsObservable();
    countryListAsObservable
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap(
                    new Func1<WebResponse<ArrayList<Country>>, Observable<?>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<Country> call(WebResponse<ArrayList<Country>> arrayListWebResponse) {

                            return Observable.from(arrayListWebResponse.getResult());
                        }
                    })
            .map(new Func1<Country, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Country country) {
                    return country.getName();
                }
            })
            .subscribe(
                    new Action1<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(String o) {
                            Log.i("Country name", o);
                        }
                    });
```

Now there is a chance that the server itself will send failure which will be in `Response`. When this occurs I want to trigger the `Subscriber`s `onError()`.

How can I do that without breaking the chain?

Comment: Where does it currently break?

Comment: the json service I am currently using is not breaking. But if it were to break then it break in `flatMap`, i.e. when it finds that `getResult()` returns `null`;

Comment: What I mean is have you tested it to see what happens when it is the wrong result. BEcause if I understand you correctly you should check the response and if it is not what you expected raise an appropriate exception

Comment: in which operator should I throw an exception?

Comment: In the flatmap.... It shouldn't matter, if I understand rxJava correct it will find its way to onError

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried something like the code below?

```
countryListAsObservable.flatMap(new Func1<WebResponse<ArrayList<Country>>, Observable<?>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Country> call(final WebResponse<ArrayList<Country>> response) {
        if (!isValidResponse(response)) {
            return Observable.error(new Exception("Response is invalid"));
        } else {
            return Observable.from(response.getResult());
        }
    }

    public boolean isValidResponse(final WebResponse<ArrayList<Country>> response) {
        return response != null && response.getResult() != null;
    }
});
```

The idea is to modify `flatMap` function a bit and return an `Observable.error` if the response isn't valid.

Comment: `Observable.error` is the correct way to do this. 

I had come across this operator but I thought it would just give me a return type error for the flatMap's function.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue,Before i was sending null in onError(null) Method.
So i went throw the RXJava lib. Inside RXJava if we send null in onError method,They have null check and call onComplete method.

Eg:-
So its better instead of sending null.Send NullPointerException("volley returns null")